# trying to avoid Grow heap (frag case)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with pageOffscreenPageLimit set to 1 (3 pages in total). I use it to display 4 bitmaps for each page. Bitmaps are loaded asynchronously, scaled down and all that stuff to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions. I noticed some 'stalls' scrolling the pages due to GC, here some piece of log:

```
03-22 13:05:06.320: V/test(11448): onPageSelected(2)
03-22 13:05:06.840: V/test(11448): destroyItem(0)
03-22 13:05:06.850: V/test(11448): instantiateItem(3)
03-22 13:05:06.900: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4578K, 29% free 15567K/21703K, paused 24ms
03-22 13:05:06.900: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.265MB for 3128360-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:06.930: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 18622K/21703K, paused 27ms
03-22 13:05:06.990: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 49K, 15% free 18636K/21703K, paused 1ms+4ms
03-22 13:05:07.060: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3221K, 25% free 16298K/21703K, paused 21ms
03-22 13:05:07.060: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.979MB for 3128360-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.100: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 19353K/21703K, paused 1ms+3ms
03-22 13:05:07.170: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3130K, 22% free 17026K/21703K, paused 20ms
03-22 13:05:07.170: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.694MB for 3131424-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.210: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 20084K/21703K, paused 1ms+3ms
03-22 13:05:07.240: V/test(11448): onPageSelected(3)
03-22 13:05:07.270: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 8% free 20053K/21703K, paused 22ms
03-22 13:05:07.270: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.359MB for 729656-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.290: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 20765K/22471K, paused 20ms
03-22 13:05:07.320: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3094K, 22% free 17739K/22471K, paused 19ms
03-22 13:05:07.330: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.386MB for 3128360-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.350: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 20793K/22471K, paused 20ms
03-22 13:05:07.390: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 8% free 20799K/22471K, paused 1ms+3ms
03-22 13:05:07.490: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 8% free 20772K/22471K, paused 27ms
03-22 13:05:07.490: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.061MB for 729656-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.520: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 21484K/23239K, paused 21ms
03-22 13:05:07.760: V/test(11448): destroyItem(1)
03-22 13:05:07.760: V/test(11448): instantiateItem(4)
03-22 13:05:07.820: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6063K, 34% free 15558K/23239K, paused 24ms
03-22 13:05:07.820: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.526MB for 3411216-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.850: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 19K, 19% free 18869K/23239K, paused 19ms
03-22 13:05:07.900: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 19% free 18908K/23239K, paused 1ms+4ms
03-22 13:05:07.960: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3463K, 30% free 16334K/23239K, paused 20ms
03-22 13:05:07.960: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.284MB for 3411216-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:07.980: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 16% free 19665K/23239K, paused 21ms
03-22 13:05:08.030: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 16% free 19674K/23239K, paused 1ms+3ms
03-22 13:05:08.100: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3433K, 27% free 17033K/23239K, paused 22ms
03-22 13:05:08.100: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.966MB for 3411216-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:08.140: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 13% free 20363K/23239K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-22 13:05:08.220: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3407K, 24% free 17749K/23239K, paused 19ms
03-22 13:05:08.220: I/dalvikvm-heap(11448): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.666MB for 3411216-byte allocation
03-22 13:05:08.260: D/dalvikvm(11448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 10% free 21079K/23239K, paused 1ms+4ms
```

the Heap Size remains at 24Mb and don't grow. Also, in the destroyItem I try to free the ImageView, setting the drawables and callbacks to null. Can I improve the performance or this is a normal behaviour?

Comment: How much you are scaling down? You can try to match Screen DPI to image DPI. If your screen is small their is no reason to load a huge image.

Comment: I scale down the images to the real size, with inSampleSize to the maximum power of 2 bigger or equal to the desired size and then creating a scaled bitmap. My concern is about the Grow heap (frag case), as you can see there is enough room to allocate the new bitmap, but the 'frag case' raises, I realize it's because the fragmentation of memory, can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have two options considering you are using **Viewpager and Imageviews**

**About image views** try to use  powerful image downloading and caching library for Android like **Picasso**,latest **Volley** Imageloading(really helpful for large size images) to improve the image loading capabilities in a efficient way.

**About Viewpager** you have to use efficient adapter **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**:
This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.

please think before you are using FragmentPagerAdapter becouse it stores the whole fragment in memory, and could increase a memory overhead if a large amount of fragments are used in ViewPager. In contrary its sibling, FragmentStatePagerAdapter only stores the savedInstanceState of fragments, and destroys all the fragments when they lose focus. Therefore FragmentStatePagerAdapter should be used when we have to use dynamic fragments, like fragments with widgets, as their data could be stored in the savedInstanceState. Also it wont affect the performance even if there are large number of fragments. In contrary its sibling FragmentPagerAdapter should be used when we need to store the whole fragment in memory. When I say the whole fragment is kept in memory it means, its instances wont be destroyed and would create a memory overhead. Therefore it is advised to use FragmentPagerAdapter only when there are low number of fragments for ViewPager. It would be even better if the fragments are static, since they would not be having large amount of objects whose instances would be stored. Hope this clears out the difference between Android FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Try to learn [Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git) android [gallary](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery) app example, use image view loading animations to make a great user experience.

I hope this will solves your grow heap problems.

Credits:[FragmentPagerAdapter vs FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://www.truiton.com/2013/06/android-fragmentpageradapter-vs-fragmentstatepageradapter/)